# PHP DOMDocument and DOMXpath - get all input/select/textarea names

Tags: php, domdocument, domxpath

I'm trying to create an array that contains all of the input/select/textarea names from the HTML I provide to the DOMDocument class.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I can't figure out how to get the element's name.  Can anyone help me?  this is what I've tried to far

```
// Parse the FORM data into HTML
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($form['FORM_DATA']);
// Use DOMXPath query to pull the input, select and textarea fields
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$col = $xpath->query('//input|//textarea|//select');
if(is_object($col)){
    foreach( $col as $node ) {
        echo $node->nodeValue.'<br />';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
echo $node->getAttribute('name').'<br />';
```